# discord.py bot hosted on heroku wont go online

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

I decided to use heroku to run my bot 24/7. I deployed, saw my dyno running, no errors and it was even switched on. I expected the bot to come online because of the deploy but it just stayed offline.

Here is my bot code:

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
import random
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle

TOKEN = 'XXXXX'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

client.remove_command('help')

status = cycle(['Helping my Creator!', 'Moderating this server. smh'])

messages = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print('Bot has connected.')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global messages
    messages +-1

    bad_words = [(just a list of bad words)]

    for word in bad_words:
        if message.content.count(word) > 0:
            print('Someone said a bad word')
            await message.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    await client.process_commands(message)

@tasks.loop(minutes = 5)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(next(status)))

@client.command()
async def cheese(ctx):
    responses = ["Here's some Parmesan.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Pecorino.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Manchego.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Grana-Padano.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Cheddar.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Gouda.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Harvati.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Gruyere.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Gorgonzola.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Stilton.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Roquefort.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Danish Blue.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Brie.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Camembert.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Double Creme White.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Cream Cheese.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Feta.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Mozzarella.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Burrata.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Chevre.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Goat Brie.:cheese:",
                 "Here's some Blue Goat Cheese.:cheese:"]
    await ctx.send(random.choice(responses))

 @client.command()
 async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
     member = ctx.author if not member else member

     embed = discord.Embed(colour = member.color, timestamp = 
     ctx.message.created_at)

     embed.set_author(name = f"User info - {member}")
     embed.set_thumbnail(url = member.avatar_url)
     embed.set_footer(text = f"Requested by {ctx.author}", icon_url = 
     ctx.author.avatar_url)

     embed.add_field(name = "ID:", value = member.id)
     embed.add_field(name = "Guild name:", value = member.display_name)

     embed.add_field(name = "Created at:", value 
     member.created_at.strftime("%a, %d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
     embed.add_field(name = "Joined at:", value = 
     member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))

     embed.add_field(name = "Bot?", value = member.bot)

     await ctx.send(embed = embed)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Here is my procfile:

```
worker: python3 modbotv4.py
```

My requirements.txt file:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
dnspython==1.16.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
```

And my runtime.txt file:

```
python-3.8.3
```

If there is anything I should add in any of the files in order to make my bot go online, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When run myself, the code you provided throws a few errors

1st being on line 69 and 70, the last @client.command() and async definition are indented by 1 space, but this may just be an error when pasted into stack overflow

```
 @client.command()
 async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
^
```

2nd being there is a missing equals sign

```
embed.add_field(name = "Created at:", value 
member.created_at.strftime("%a, %d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
```

where it should be

```
embed.add_field(name = "Created at:", value =
                                            ^ equals sign
member.created_at.strftime("%a, %d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
```

The code then runs fine

Sorry that it took so long

Comment: but is doesnt seem to launch even if i have it

Comment: have you enabled the worker like here https://imgur.com/a/ZX8pYeY?

Comment: Does the program run fine on your local computer, or does it print an error to terminal

Comment: in the worker file, have you tried changing python3 to python

Comment: Have you looked at the logs in your terminal using heroku —logs

Comment: well it works fine on my local computer, i first tried python, but it didnt work, so i switched to python3 and yes i have and this is the last line i saw: `2020-05-29T08:34:15.063791+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to down`

Comment: Have you tried redeploying eg ‘git add .’ ‘git commit -am “a”’ ‘git push heroku master’

Comment: The error is on the heroku side, might be something with the config

Comment: No problem, sorry it took so long, i couldnt run your code until a while ago. Glad it works now, can you mark as an answer? thanks!

Comment: since it helped me, sure!